# CSS : Fixed height % for child elements aligned vertically at any zoom level

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I have a vertical sidebar which is composed of 3 elements, a header, a body and a footer.
[image]

The Html of this sidebar is like this:

```
<div id="parent" class="flex-grow-1" style = "position: absolute; flex-direction: column">
    <div style="background-color:yellow">A</div>
    <div style="background-color:green;">B</div>
    <div style="background-color:red">C</div>
</div>
```

Now i want to maintain consistency of the heights of these divs A , B and C **at any zoom level and at any resolution of the browser/screen**. Something like :

1. height of A should always remain at 25% of the height of the parent and it should stick to the top.
2. height of B should always remain 50% of the height of the parent and it should remain at the middle. Also, B is a **List** of items. I am compressing the list with overflow: auto and giving it a scrollbar.
3. height of C should always remain 25% of the height of the parent and it should stick to the bottom.

The parent element's position is always "absolute" and I will not be able to change it as it is a child of another html and so on.
So i want to know, what kind of css settings should i give to achieve the requirement

Comment: You mean [`height: 25%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. My preference would go out to CSS Grid as it allows the parent to control the placement and dimensions of the children.

Here I've created a grid with 1 implicit column and 3 explicit rows. Each row has a percentage value that represents the size of the element on the Y axis.

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 50% 25%;
  height: 500px; /* For demonstration purposes */
  width: 200px; /* For demonstration purposes */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="flex-grow-1" style="position: absolute;">
  <div style="background-color: yellow">A</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color: red">C</div>
</div>
```